# instance of external program inside a buffer

Tags: java, windows, streaming, multiple-instances

i have a project that involve the streaming of the image of a running program.

the program can be anything, a video player, a stock control, with any type of visual stuff inside a windows.

so, i need to open a instance of this program, put it on a non-viewable buffer (the instance should be not be shown at the main screen of the app or OS) and stream the image (on the future i will need to interact with it, but let's leave that for now). and  i don't have any idea how to do it.

i want to do it in java, i will be working on windows platform, so anyone can give me a guide/hint of where i can look about this? (i'm not expecting a solution, just some library or code reference that will put me on the right path to solve this)

Regards,
Shadow.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.awt.Robot` to take one screen shot, some form of `Timer` to get multiple screen shots.